# Columns in views get displaced when altering table in MS-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am occasionally forced to use MS-SQL, so my knowledge of it is basic. I'm sure the following problem is piece of cake for an MS-SQL expert, but for me this looks really like a nasty bug:

Say I have a simple table containing a person's last name, first name, and email, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.people
(
lastName varchar(50) NULL,
firstName varchar(50) NULL,
email varchar(50) NULL
)
```

Now I'm going to create a view so I have some pre-concated fields, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW v_people AS
SELECT
    people.*,
    people.lastName + ' ' + people.firstName AS concatName
FROM people
```

Now I notice that I forgot the Phone number field, and alter the original table, but ONLY the table, NOT the view:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.people ADD
phone varchar(50) NULL
```

Cool, also works. But what now happened to the view is quite horrible: The view field 'concatName' does not contain the concated names, but the Phone Numbers, even if the view fields are STILL the same amount and names!

It seems that MS-SQL is just moving the data columns within the view without updating the column definitions. Quite horrible scenario, if you forget to update views that depends on tables you alter...

Do I have overseen something, or am I really responsible for always checking / altering all the views if I just add a new table column? Is there a way to let the MS-SQL server at least throw a warning about depending views?

I noticed that it does not happen if the view is constructed like this:

```
CREATE VIEW v_people AS
SELECT
    people.lastName + ' ' + people.firstName AS concatName,
    people.*
FROM people
```

But for me this just looks like a nasty workaround....

Any hints?

Comment: One of many reasons why using SELECT * is bad.  Be explicit!

Comment: @Joe - In a view definition it's not too bad (except for the issue in this question) as long as you aren't then doing `SELECT *` from the View. I use `*` in CTEs all the time which conceptually aren't that different.

Comment: Cannot see why this should be bad. If you take PostgreSQL, e.g., it internally expands it to single columns, which is OK. But what happens on MS-SQL here seems quite... well... unexpected... At least I expect a warning...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call `sp_refreshview 'YourView'` after altering the definition of tables selected from with `*`.

Comment: So I have to manually do this to every depending view? Sometimes this can be quite a lot... Is there a 'batch' way, without exactly knowing the views concerned in advance?

Comment: @AlexSchenkel - Not really. You would need to query the dependency information to find out referencing Views. Another option would be to not use `*` and explicitly list all columns and create the view `WITH SCHEMABINDING` then it won't let you alter the table without first dropping all affected views that you then manually review and update...

Answer (score 2):

As Martin mentions, you need to refresh the view if you change the definition of the underlying table and use `SELECT *` in your view.

A really easy way to avoid this is to **NEVER USE `SELECT *`** in your views!

It's a terrible practice and can cause all sorts of issues.  The only "benefit" is that you don't need to type out field names the ONE TIME you define the view.

Comment: OK, I see that it is a bad practice, but hey, what MS-SQL does here is just wrong. Either it should warn when altering the table, or expand the .* on view creation time, or not allow it... But this way one has no indication that something is wrong.

Comment: @AlexSchenkel - I don't think it's the database's responsibility to tell you when you do something foolish that may cause issues with your data structures.  The expectation is that you or your DBA will know what objects exist and what they reference since **YOU PROGRAMMED THEM**

Comment: Yes, this is the ideal world idea... unfortunately what happens a lot is: the former programmer left, no documentation around, and you in front of a heap of views... that's what actually happended, and I just won't take it that the DB reacts a bit... sorry... stupid in my pov. But thans, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered years ago, the solution is to use `sp_refreshview 'YourView'` for the affected views.

Since one of the follow-up questions was if you need to do it for each view manually afterwards, I want to answer that: You could search for views that have a * in their definition (surrounded by SELECT and FROM) by using `sys.sql_modules`.

```
  SELECT schemas.name 'schema',
         objects.name 'object',
         sql_modules.definition 'definition'
    FROM sys.sql_modules
    JOIN sys.objects ON sql_modules.object_id=objects.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas ON objects.schema_id=schemas.schema_id
   WHERE definition LIKE '%SELECT%*%FROM%'
     AND objects.type = 'V'
ORDER BY schemas.name, objects.name
```

You can now take that and iterate over them using a cursor.

```
 DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT TOP 10 schemas.name + '.' + objects.name 'View'
    FROM sys.sql_modules
    JOIN sys.objects ON sql_modules.object_id=objects.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas ON objects.schema_id=schemas.schema_id
   WHERE definition LIKE '%SELECT%*%FROM%'
     AND objects.type = 'V'
ORDER BY schemas.name, objects.name

DECLARE @View VARCHAR(128)
OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @View
    
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_refreshview @View
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @View
END
```